# AngularJS: Using $routeProvider with multiple modules?

Tags: angularjs, mean-stack

I am building an angular app with multiple modules. Each module is a view component (rather than having one giant module with all the view components) as recommended by John Papa's Angular style guide. However, whereas previously I could just do...

```
angular.module('app').config( <config for all client routes and their controllers> )
```

I've realized that I can't do this since controllers are on separate modules now. So, I've split off the $routeProvider login into their respective files:

```
angular.module('app.<modulename>').config( <config for app.modulename routes and its controllers> );
```

However, when I navigate to any route not defined on my `app` module, I see an empty page, so it seems the `$routeProvider` for other modules doesn't seem to be working. How do I make multiple modules share the `ng-view`?

Comment: Are you including the `app.<modulename>` modules in the dependency array for your main app module, ie `angular.module('app', ['app.module1', 'app.module2', 'etc'])`? For the modules requiring `$routeProvider`, are you including `ngRoute` in their dependency list?

Comment: @Phil ah, good call, I forgot to list the module dependencies and also injected `$routeProvider` instead of `ngRoute`. Can you post that as an answer? Also, it looks like that fix exposed an $injector error: "app.<module>" is not available! Any ideas what I'm missing? I've listed a script reference to it in my index.html file

Comment: @Phil nevermind, the second part was due to a snippet typo... thanks! Please submit your comment as an answer so I can accept :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for your modules to be configured, you need to include them in the main application module via the dependency array. For example, say you have the following modules...

```
angular.module('app.module1', ['ngRoute'])
    .config(function($routeProvider) { ... })

angular.module('app.module2', ['ngRoute'])
    .config(function($routeProvider) { ... })
```

You configure and include them via

```
angular.module('app', ['app.module1', 'app.module2'])
```